# Как сделать запуск FileZilla по имени из терминала?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filezilla

Вопрос такой. Скачиваю программу для **линукса** (`Ubuntu 18.04`), например **FileZilla**. Там есть бинарник для запуска. Как мне сделать так, чтобы запускать её в терминале можно было в фоновом режиме и прописав только имя:

```
filezilla
```

Запуск с добавлением в конце команды `&` не приводит к нужному результату.

> UPD 1 Сделал запуск по команде

- Переместил скачанную **FileZilla3** в директорию `/bin/FileZilla3`
- Вывел в переменную `$PATH` и добавил в неё: `export PATH="$PATH:/bin/FileZilla3/bin/filezilla"`;
- Так же подправил файл `/home/user-name/.bashrc` (чтобы не вводить вышеуказанную команду каждый раз при запуске системы): `export PATH="$PATH:/bin/FileZilla3/bin/filezilla"`;
- Так же **FileZilla3** попросила установить модуль **canberra-gtk-module** ([как установить](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed));

Я почти доволен. **FileZilla3** запускается теперь из любого места по команде `filezilla`. Но мне хочется не видеть подобное при запуске программы командой `filezilla &`:

> Reading locale option from /home/user-name/.config/filezilla/filezilla.xml
> wxD-Bus: Signal from /org/freedesktop/DBus, member NameAcquired
> wxD-Bus: Reply with serial 2
> wxD-Bus: Reply to RegisterClient, our object path is /org/gnome/SessionManager/Client32

И не хочется вводить `nohup filezilla &`, так как автоматически выводится информация `nohup: ввод игнорируется, вывод добавляется в 'nohup.out'` и висит процесс в терминале (после нажатия <kbd>Enter</kbd> выходит из процесса). А хочется вводить просто `filezilla` и далее передавалось управление опять терминалу (можно было вводить новые команды).

Так же есть проблема при закрытии программы (из графического интерфейса):

> wxD-Bus: Unregistered

Только после нажатия <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> процесс завершается с выводом сообщения:

```
[2]-  Завершён        filezilla
[3]+  Завершён        nohup filezilla
```

---

> UPD 2 Сделал alias ([как создать alias](https://losst.ru/poleznye-alias-linux)), как подсказал [@Total Pusher](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/287469/total-pusher)
>
> UPD 3 Можно запускать без создания `alias`, нажав комбинацию клавиш <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> и нет никаких уведомлений (для меня, это не плохое решение), но я всё таки создам `alias` чтобы писать только `fz`. Спасибо [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal)

Comment: По возможности в линуксе, в частности в убунту программы надо не скачивать, а устанавливать из репозитория

Comment: alias filezilla="filezilla &"

Comment: @TotalPusher да, отличное решение. Но что делать с процессами?

Comment: А можно узнать: нафига? Просто интерес или есть какая-то конкретная задача?

Comment: @donRumata, я давно этой прогой пользуюсь. Ещё со времён винды. Как-то привык и нравится она.  И хочется запускать и закрывать её без лишних проблем. А тут получается если ты запускаешь её без `&` то висит процесс, а если с `&`, то вклиниваются процессы.

Comment: @donRumata уж, хрен с ним с информационными сообщениями. Просто уж если запускается в фоне, то чтобы больше не лезла в терминал.

Comment: @doox911 возможно глупость скажу, но почему бы не запускать через Alt+F2?)

Comment: @andreymal БОМБА! Спасибо! А где прочитать, что это за окно и это только в `ubuntu` и только в  `gui`?

Comment: @doox911 только в gui, но вроде во всех популярных DE. В некоторых DE ещё по клавише Windows можно открыть местный аналог меню «Пуск» и в тамошнее поле поиска вбить название программы (не помню, есть ли в убунте)

Comment: filezilla используется для работы на сервере? есть более удобный способ работы: подмонтировать каталог удаленной машины себе в файловую систему. Будет выглядеть как работа с локальными файлами. Технология называется FUSE, а монтируется командой mount, в том числе виндовые шары (mount.cifs). `mymount site.ru` - и все! Задайте отдельный вопрос на SO, если не сможете разобраться.

Comment: @TotalPusher О супер. Попробую. Не подскажите в чём проблема делаю всё тоже самое на другом компе  `Command 'filezilla' not found` хотя если, например в корне, прописать `/bin/FileZilla3/bin/filezilla` она открывается? В чём проблема может быть?

Comment: Linux ищет команду в PATH. Сделайте `echo "$PATH"` - увидите перечисление каталогов через `:`. Приемлемых варианта два: 1) сделать симлинк, например так: `sudo ln -s /bin/FileZilla3/bin/filezilla /bin/filezilla` (вы неудачно поставили FZ в /bin/ - это не Linux way, в том каталоге одни бинарники или симлинки) 2) добавить каталог с бинарником в PATH (в данном случае НЕ рекомендую, это вариант подходит если в каталоге куча программ, которые хотелось бы запускать)

Comment: @TotalPusher а куда лучше закидывать? Сделал симлинк, всё заработало. Причём удалил всё из `$PATH`. Почему мой вариант не работает?

Comment: Конкретно в этом случае `/usr/bin`, куда и ставится менеджером пакетов. http://fliplinux.com/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-linux.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Основной способ

```
nohup filezilla &
```

### Вариант для zsh

Если используется альтернативу башу в виде `zsh` или `Oh My Zsh` (мой выбор), то:

```
filezilla &!
```

### Забыли открепить сразу

Если забыли открепить, а программа уже запущена таким способом:

```
filezilla
```

То переключаемся в терминал и жмем `Ctrl + Z` - программа встанет на паузу, а мы получим доступ к командной строке и увидим:

```
[1]  + 32696 suspended  filezilla
```

далее вводим `bg` - программа начнет выполняться на заднем плане, в терминале будет

```
[1]  + 32696 continued  filezilla
```

Теперь вводим:

```
disown %1
```

Программа "открепится" от процесса терминала, и терминал можно закрыть.

Comment: Подправил вопрос, дополните ответ)